# Reporting tools compatible with Genexus

Tags: reporting, genexus

I need to use a reporting tool with genexus for web development. Genexus proposes to use the generation of reports through Procedure-type objects, but these do not have the possibility of generating them through queries similar to what can be done with Crystal Report.
As far as I know it has no possibility to integrate with Crystal Report.
Do you know any reporting tool that can be easily integrated with Genexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

speaking of Crystal Report I think you are using .net as a generator. If you had used Java you could have adopted Jasper Report. For .net, on the other hand, at the moment I don't think there is anything "standard". We use different approaches based on the type of report. For some reports we continue to make them with the procedure, others with the query object but for documents, such as contracts that need to be managed dynamically with the possibility of inserting or removing sections but which must also dynamically manage the page change, we have integrated an external DLL (integrated as an external object) and we generate the report in html.

Comment: The tool used is SelectPDF.

Answer (score 3):

In GeneXus, you have the possibility to create queries to extract information from your database and then present with different types of charts, pivot table, tables, maps, and cards.

Also, you have a dashboard object to integrate many queries in a same dashboard. [Here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?33991,Query%20Object%20Usage%20Example) you can learn how to build this and [here](https://reporting.samples.genexus.com/dashboardcases.aspx) you can see a showcase running with different examples

This Knowledge Base is open source, so [here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?49086,KB%3AReporting+Showcase) you can see how to get it.

Comment: Those objects do not allow to write queries in SQL!